# How do I deploy Qbit Ninja Server?

Tags: qbitninja

How do I deploy [Qbit Ninja](https://github.com/MetacoSA/QBitNinja) Server developed by Nicolas Dorier on a production server?

Answer (score 2):

sorry there is no documentation.

The console application QbitNinja.Console.Listener is an app which connect to a trusted full node and push the data into Azure Storage. Due to latency, you should run that on a VM hosted in azure in the same region as your storage.

The website can be deployed as a Azure Web App, it only query the data indexed by the Listener.

If you have basic knowledge in ASP.NET and Azure, this is easy to setup. If you do not have, I advise you to start by learning about how to deploy a web app on azure.